# In Bootstrap 4, the ".navbar-toggler" button will not float right

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I do not know what I am doing wrong but it seems like what ever I try, I cannot get the `.navbar-toggler` button to float to the right. I'm sure I am just overlooking something small, but I don't know what is wrong.

Here is my code.

> NOTE: You might need to shrink window to see the button.

```css
.title-bar {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.company-name {
  font-family: "Trajan Pro";
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0px auto -15px 5px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

#seal {
  margin: -50px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark title-bar">
  <div class="container-fluid title-bar">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row d-md-none">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-flex" href="#" style="margin: 0px 10px">
          <img style="margin: 0; height:65px;" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/08/10/10/coat-of-arms-1186256_960_720.png" id="seal" alt="lion head" />
          <div class="company-name">
            <div class="text-center">Fake</div>
            <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 85%; margin-top: -20px;">Co.</div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-center ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-md-block">
        <a class="navbar-brand company-name" href="#">Fake Company</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-secondary navbar-dark">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-flex">
      <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Profle</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center">
        <img class="d-none d-md-inline" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/08/10/10/coat-of-arms-1186256_960_720.png" id="seal" alt="coa" style="max-width:110px; width:50%" />
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="d-sm-none">
  extra small
</div>
<div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">
  small
</div>
<div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">
  medium
</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">
  large
</div>
<div class="d-none d-xl-block">
  extra large
</div>
```

Or see it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/makpo/urdvgkf8/8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navbar-header` doesn't exist anymore. Remove it and make the inner flex dev `w-100` (width:100%)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark title-bar">
    <div class="container-fluid title-bar">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row d-md-none w-100">
            <a class="navbar-brand d-flex" href="#" style="margin: 0px 10px">
            <img style="margin: 0; height:65px;" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/08/10/10/coat-of-arms-1186256_960_720.png" id="seal" alt="lion head" />
                <div class="company-name">
                    <div class="text-center">Fake</div>
            <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 85%; margin-top: -20px;">Co.</div>
            </div>
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-center ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="d-none d-md-block">
                <a class="navbar-brand company-name" href="#">Fake Company</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zxjk3pLn/

Comment: That fixed this issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Add this so its container `.navbar-header` spreads across the whole width and therefore allows it to go right:

```
.navbar-header {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.title-bar {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.company-name {
    font-family: "Trajan Pro";
    font-size: 36px;
    margin: 0px auto -15px 5px;
}
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
}
#seal {
    margin: -50px auto;
}
.navbar-header {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark title-bar">
   <div class="container-fluid title-bar">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <div class="d-flex flex-row d-md-none">
      <a class="navbar-brand d-flex" href="#" style="margin: 0px 10px">
       <img style="margin: 0; height:65px;" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/08/10/10/coat-of-arms-1186256_960_720.png" id="seal" alt="lion head" />
       <div class="company-name">
        <div class="text-center">Fake</div>
        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 85%; margin-top: -20px;">Co.</div>
       </div>
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-center ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
     </div>
     <div class="d-none d-md-block">
      <a class="navbar-brand company-name" href="#">Fake Company</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-secondary navbar-dark">
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-flex">
     <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Profle</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center">
            <img class="d-none d-md-inline" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/08/10/10/coat-of-arms-1186256_960_720.png" id="seal" alt="coa" style="max-width:110px; width:50%" />
          </li>
     <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item flex-fill text-center"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
    <div class="d-sm-none">
      extra small
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">
      medium
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">
      large
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-xl-block">
      extra large
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.container-fluid` div is set to `display: flex`, so elements nested directly within it are not automatically taking up 100% width. This includes the `.navbar-header` element. If you temporarily add a color background to `.navbar-header` you will see it does not fill the `.container-fluid`element.

So whilst the `.navbar-toggler` is pushing to the right of its parent, the problem is the parent isn't expanding. You can add `width: 100%` or `flex-grow: 1` to the `.navbar-header` to fix this - both will cause it to fill the width of the parent. Because the parent is a flex container I prefer to set via flex-grow as it feels more logical to me, but both will have the same effect in this case.